# Best way to integrate Paypal with Ruby

Tags: ruby, paypal

I have a Web application using Jruby and Sinatra (App Engine) and I want to use Paypal.  What is a good way to do this?  Gem from Rubygems?  (There are 30, most of them seem to be abandoned...)  Or stick with SDK libs from Paypal?  Unfortunately they are very Rails oriented...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider [Active Merchant](http://activemerchant.org/), which is an actively developed, mature library. Even though it integrates well with Rails, it can be just as well used as a stand-alone library, and it supports many methods of payment, in case you will at some point consider adding methods different from PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ruby-toolbox.com ([Paypal](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=paypal)), you can see which project is most popular

Answer (score 0):

I created a Gem to do just this: https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-paypal

You use it just by adding a `payment` block in the application

```
payment :complete do |p|
    # check the price is correct, then
    # do whatever
end
```